# Is there a on/off sensor for smart home actions

Tags: actions-on-google

I've been looking for a way to implement a simple sensor that only has an on or off state.
As the simple [SensorState](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/traits/sensorstate#supported-sensors) does not supporta simple on/off state I tried using a [Switch](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/guides/switch) with an [OnOff](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/traits/onoff) trait, and set the [queryOnlyOnOff attribute](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/traits/onoff#device-attributes) to true

The description of the attribute is `Indicates if the device can only be queried for state information, and cannot be controlled through commands.` As of the app still showing on/off buttons, is commands only for voice commands? If so Google needs to add a simple sensor we already have the trait for it we just need to add a simple detected/notdetected sensor to the [SensorState](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/traits/sensorstate#supported-sensors) if there is not already. Any ideas how to work around this?

Edit 1:
My current `SYNC` response https://gist.githubusercontent.com/DRSchlaubi/7099dc289858ae6dba72e54311fa728f/raw/4f3f9506cfe27701be00db438477c3bed8a6b0ec/sync.json

EDIT 2:
I see google specifically lists an example for sensors [here](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/traits/onoff#examples)

but the example is very vague and looks like you have to add it to the top-level payload which does not work as well as adding it to the attributes object

EDIT 3: I tried switching from the Switch device to a [Sensor](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/guides/sensor) device but now it does no longer display the state in the app probably Sensor does not support StateOnOff?

Edit 4: on the sensor page it says `These traits are recommended, if applicable to your device. However, you are free to mix and match from all available traits to best match your existing product functionality.` however the OnOff state does not seem to display anything

Comment: can you share the `SYNC` response payload for your device?

Comment: Sorry for my late response I edited my post so it now contains a copy of the SYNC response